Image cropping for excel creation with apache POI
I am currently creating an Excel file using Apache POI. I already added images to one column correctly. But now I'd like to crop the images to only show the relevant part in the middle of the image. Like in this example image, I wanna use only the red rectangle:
.
I couldn't find anything in the documentation (or elsewhere) about cropping of or zooming into images. Does anyone know a way to achieve this in POI?
Tried: Added images to images in Excel, read documentation and researched possible solutions on the internet.

Picture crop is not directly supported by Apache POI upto now.
If the need is only for XSSF (Office Open XML, *.xlsx) and XSSFPicture, then this can be solved like so:
This sets srcRrect property in blipFillto crop the picture. The values of left, top, right and bottom are percent values,. For left and right in percent of picture width and for top and bottom in percent of picture height.  There 100000 are 100%, so 25000 are 25%, 25500 are 25.5% and so on. This is to avoid floating point in values.
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ExcelCreatePicture {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(true); String filePath = "./Excel.xlsx";
 
  // add PNG image to workbook
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("./wjJTbSSY.png");
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
  int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
  in.close();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   
  // create anchor for picture shape
  CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
  ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
  anchor.setCol1(1);
  anchor.setRow1(1); 

  // create PNG picture shape
  Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
  picture.resize();
  
  // only XSSF; set srcRrect property in blipFill to crop the picture
  org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture xssfPicture = (org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture)picture; 
  xssfPicture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().addNewSrcRect();
  int i100Percent = 100000;
  xssfPicture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().getSrcRect().setL(i100Percent*2475/10000);
  xssfPicture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().getSrcRect().setT(i100Percent*20/100);
  xssfPicture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().getSrcRect().setR(i100Percent*22/100);
  xssfPicture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().getSrcRect().setB(i100Percent*315/1000);
   
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}

Result:

